# CLI app in PHP that asks for name and email address in php

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I am working on creating a PHP CLI basic script that asks for name and email address and validates email and if everything is correct would just print the information.

I have done some basic structure as in code below :

```
<?php
echo "Enter your first name : ";
$firstName = trim(fgets(STDIN));
echo "Enter your last name : ";
$lastName = trim(fgets(STDIN));
echo "Enter your email address : ";
$email = trim(fgets(STDIN));
$validEmail = validateEmailAddress($email);
if(!$validEmail){
    echo "Invalid Email Address";
}else{
      echo "Welcome $firstName $lastName";
      } 

function validateEmailAddress($email)
{
    $validEmail = true;    
    $regex = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/'; 
    if (!preg_match($regex, $email)) {
     echo "Invalid email address. Please try again.";
     $validEmail = false;
    }          
    return $validEmail;
}
?>
```

Currently the  code stops when I enter an invalid email address, how do I make it interactive, so that if its incorrect it asks user to enter it again until he enters an correct email address.
The current code starts again to enter the names which is not interactive.

Also, would be great to know the best standards I should follow when creating such application (CLI), would it be better to do it in OOPS way, as this is my uni test.

Comment: The code just stops when you enter a valid email address too! So what is the  question

Comment: _if everything is correct would just print the information_ Print what information??

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly The question is to make it interactive, so that if a user enters an invalid email address it prompts that the email is invalid and asks to enter it again until a valid email address is achieved.

Comment: Then you need to add a loop so that the question can be asked and answered again and again until you get a satisfactory result

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly I just achieved it with a while loop, also would like to know if I should make the code in OOPS style, can that make me gain some extra points in test

Comment: Thats COMPLETELY up to you

Comment: Thankyou @RiggsFolly